# Loop through columns and copy and paste cells A to B

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a simple code but i have not able to crack it. i want the macro to  run and pick up a value (2), and copy and paste the cells A to C , into sheet 2. The code below does copy the Cells A-B and pastes. I failing on the loop . I want it to loop from 1st row to last row. please.

```
Sub Tier_2()
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(3, 3)).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't for your specific situation, but the concept is what you are looking for.  You should be able to do some research with what I'm showing you and figure it out.

```
lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row   'gets last row of Source sheet
For x = 1 to lastRow
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, 1) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 1)    'copy data from Sheet1 to Sheet2 row x
Next x    'loop and add one to x
```

You can use variables for either the row or column numbers in either the source or target sheets.  You can insert another loop inside the first one.  I'm not sure of what you are looking for, but your question didn't seem to have a loop in it at all.

If that doesn't get you going in the right direction try "Do While Loop" in a search.

EDIT:  Updated the formula to better reflect idea.

Comment: I changed the code and added comments for you to make a little more sense

Comment: On a side note - In the newer XML style workbooks there are over 1 million rows, so for consistency across versions it's better to use something like `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` than specify a row number for this type of function.

Comment: Good call. I usually put that specifically for the people who happen to be using older Excel versions.  I will modify the answer.